# How to add index in hazelcast

Tags: indexing, hazelcast

I am new to hazelcast and I have read everywhere that adding index will improve query performance in hazelcast. I am storing my data in hazelcast maps with key as string and value as Portable.
If i assume my value will be something like this:

```
type Student struct {
   Name string
   ID int
}
```

golang documentation for adding index says `You should make sure to add the indexes before adding entries to this map..`
So I have few doubts on this:

1. Do i need to add index **each time** before putting value to a map? or is it only one time in the application life time?
2. Any thing needs to enabled specifically on server side for this map which needs indexing support?

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to add index each time before putting value to a map? or is it only one time in the application life time?

No, it is a one-time configuration.

> Any thing needs to enabled specifically on server side for this map which needs indexing support?

You have to define the index for the map in the hazelcast configuration (you can do it in XML or YAML, or programmatically) as described at https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/#indexing-queries

Comment: Will indexing help If most of my hazelcast operations are using PREDICATE KEYs?